# JSX or HTML autocompletion in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

Is there any way to use components or HTML completion in Visual Studio Code? Because typing each letter manually is not good idea when we have classes like Bootstrap etc. For example completion as in Emmet: `ul>li*2>a`

```
var React = require('react');

var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (

            <nav className="navbar navbar-defaullt">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">
                        <img width="50" height="50" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
                    <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

                );
                }
                });
module.exports  = Header;
```

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/18427#issuecomment-286013222

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Visual studio code detect .jsx extensions and add emmet support by default ( i'm using VS code 1.8.1)

But if you prefer to use .js extention for all your react files - you can associate JavaScript React mode with .js files in bottom right corner of VS Code window.

[How to do this step by step (gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4n8H.gif)

[image]

### Update 2021

For those who just want to copy-paste the code:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
  "javascript": "jsx"
}
```

If the solution above doesn't work, try this:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Tested with VS Code v1.56.2.

Comment: Could you please explain the last part a little bit more? I need to use js as the extension of all my react files.

Comment: What's not obvious from the gif is that he is pressing `ESC` to manually exit the intellisense window before pressing `TAB` to get autocompletion.

Comment: If you prefer plain text, add `"emmet.syntaxProfiles": { "javascript": "jsx" }` to your user settings…

Comment: ```"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
 "emmet.includeLanguages": {
   "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}```

Did it for me

Comment: The second worked for me perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Also don't forget to change showExpandedAbbreviation to always.

If it is

    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly",

in the **settings.json** file, then, these won't work

Or simply go to the **Show Expanded Abbreviations** section, and set it to the default, **always**.

Answer (score 310):

**2023**: Straightforward way to add JSX/HTML autocomplete for `.js` files in **React** projects...

First, open VSCode's Settings by pressing `Ctrl` + `,` (or `Cmd`+`,` on Mac). Then...

**Set with JSON:**

1. From Settings, to open settings.json, click the Open JSON button shown below. Optionally, if you don't want to set this globally, you can create a `.vscode/settings.json` file at the project root.

[image: Button for settings.json file]

2. Add these JSON values in the settings.json:

   ```
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
        "javascript": "jsx"
    }
   ```

**Set with Settings UI:**

Note that `Emmet: Syntax Profiles` still requires opening settings.json (shown above), but for anyone seeking this info, here it is...

From Settings, use the search bar to find `Emmet: Include Languages`

Click "Add item" then add a mapping for `javascript` to `javascriptreact`.

Comment: "javascript": ["javascript", "javascriptreact"] - to set it for .js and .jsx files.

Comment: THIS WORKS! However! If you have suggestions turned on, hitting tab will take the top suggestion from that list... the fix for this is to set a delay on suggestions using `Editor: Quick Suggestions Delay`. Set that to some value like 600 and you'll be able to type the element -> hit tab -> voila.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It just worked like a charm!

Comment: Also don't forget to change showExpandedAbbreviation to always.

If it is

        "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly",

in the **settings.json** file, then, these won't work

Or simply go to the **Show Expanded Abbreviations** section, and set it to the default, **always**.

Answer (score 62):

If someone is still struggling with this issue:

I have discovered that simply setting

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
     "javascript": "jsx" 
 },
```

does not enable HTML completion. But, using:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html"
}
```

does.

According to [emmet docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

> `"emmet.includeLanguages": {}`
>
> Enable emmet abbreviations in languages that are not supported by default. Add a mapping here between the language and emmet supported language.
>   Eg: `{"vue-html": "html", "javascript": "javascriptreact"}`

Comment: This worked for me.
Using
 `
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript":"javascriptreact",
    }
`
or 

`
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript":"jsx",
    }
`
did not work for me

Answer (score 53):

Just select the appropriate **Language mode** at the bottom-right on the screen: set it to **JavaScript React.**

Comment: right, I'm sure you'll be wanting to do this on every file in a large project, every time you re-open VS code...

Comment: Yeah, funny =) After update it supports jsx + emmet by default.

Comment: what support by default?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this answer

Comment: Thanks, currently it is **JavaScript JSX**

Answer (score 15):

**2018**

I'm using `VSCode` `(ver 1.27.2)`

Base on my experienced, even though I'm working with `React` . The detected language on my `VSCode` is still vanilla `JavaScript`. And emmet did not work.

- One of the ways to make it work again is change the `VSCode` detected language to `JavaScript React`. This is for single `JS` file only.

[image: vscode options]

- To change it once entirely, you need to associate it.

[image: two]

Click `Configure File Association for .js...`

[image: three]

And select `JSX` , which in my case, I already did.

[image: four]

- For Workplace Setting, and last if none of them work for you. Go to Preference of just to `ctrl + , (comma)` to open it.

Type and search for `emmet` or `Emmet`. Then copy the Setting you want to override.
In my case:

```
{
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
}
```

**Note**: I didn't try to use `jsx` only `javascriptreact`.

[image: settings]

I implemented the second and third step. And I can now do `Emmet`.

Comment: visualization helps, thank you 

Answer (score 13):

### Simple answer in 2020

First, select the *File Association* in the bottom-center-right of the window.
[image]

Second, select *Configure File Association for .js* from the menu that drops down at the top-center of the window. Change it to JavaScript React.
[image]

Comment: your screenshot was really helpful, it works, after vs code update to 1.62.3 I was unable to do this, following your screenshot helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

None of those solutions worked... but the Auto Close Tag extension does!
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Comment: Same here. Best answer.

Comment: yea i dont wanna use extension of every little feature

Answer (score 10):

**2022-2023**: The easy & Modern way to enable the auto suggestions for JSX for ReactJs is Shown in the GIF below.

for Windows =>  File > Preferences > Settings

for MacOs => Code > Preferences > Settings

then goto extensions > emmet > include languages and add `javascript` as the item and `javascriptreact` as the value

for visual reference follow the steps shown in GIF.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

## 2019 Update

---

**Auto closing tags in .html, .js, and .jsx**

Works out of the box. That is, after typing in the closing bracket to the opening tag, the closing tag will be inserted automatically.

**Emmet with basic HTML in .jsx files**

Works out of the box.

**Emmet with basic HTML in .js files:**

Add the following setting, required for Emmet abbreviation suggestions, and required for tab expansion to work consistently.

```
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
```

**Emmet with custom tags (e.g. React Components) in both .js and .jsx files**

Add the following setting:

```
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
```

Note that with this setting, Emmet will expand all words as custom tags (not just React component names)

Also note that when using Emmet to expand React components as custom tags, you have to actually choose the component name from the suggestion list and complete that first (or type out the whole name manually and close the suggestion menu with the escape key). After the word expands, you then have to tab again to get Emmet to expand the custom tag.

There's an [active feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/66107) to potentially remove this extra step (automatically expand when selecting the suggestion so that it works the same way as expanding standard html tags would).

---

**Troubleshooting**

Ensure you have the latest version of VSCode.

Ensure you did not change the following default settings:

```
"html.autoClosingTags": true,
"javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
"typescript.autoClosingTags": true,

// read the GitHub issue listed above if you're curious why this is required).
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,

// you obviously don't want javascript, javascriptreact included in here if you want Emmet to be available in those files
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "markdown"
],
```

Answer (score 6):

I went throw all answers and this config worked for me. had to include language as well as add syntaxProfile. without the trigger expansion nothing worked but now I only press Tab button to get the result.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
},
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem simply by following the steps below:

1. On the left bottom of VSCode click to Javascript
2. Then on the top, you will see a list, click on "Configure 'Javascript' language based settings"
3. Add these lines to the file:

   ```
   "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "javascript": "javascriptreact"
   }
   ```

If you want to more details, you can check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_emmet-abbreviations-in-other-file-types) link.

Answer (score 6):

1. Just go to settings in vscode.
2. You can see a search bar in setting type emmet.
3. Scroll down, there is an option include language.
4. Click on the add item button in include language.
5. Add item as javascript and value as javascriptreact.

if you get confused, please refer to the picture below:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can use The Auto Close Extention In Visual Studio Code .
ps. when you install the extension, the autocomplete won't work until you reload VS Code , just Reopen VS Code , or go to auto close tag extension and click Reload.

link of the [auto close tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) Extension

Answer (score 4):

Changing the extension from ".js" to ".jsx" will do the job. But in case you want to keep the ".js" extension follow the below steps.

Go to

**Files > Preferences > Settings**

In the settings tab, you will see two tabs named 'user' and 'workspace' (look close to the bottom of the search bar). Both the tabs will show you the same settings but user settings will affect all the projects in VS Code while workspace will affect only the current project. Choose whatever option you want, workspace or user.

And then on the left side menu bar, you have to go

**Extensions > JSON**

Then on the right side, you can see several settings. Scroll down a little bit and you will see something like this.

> JSON:Schemas
> Associate schemas to JSON files in the current project.
> Edit in settings.json

Click on "Edit in settigns.json". It will open a JSON file. Add the below code to the JSON file.

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

And save the file. Now go and check if your js file supports jsx auto-completion. This has been tested with

**VS Code version 1.61.2**.

P.S. -: Following part is only for the learners who don't know about JSON.

Copy and paste the above code to **the bottom** of the settings.json file as shown in the following image. Don't forget to add a **comma** (pointed by the red arrow) and the code should be pasted before the **last closing curly bracket** (pointed by the yellow arrow).

If you choose the workspace settings tab then there might be nothing in your settings.json file. If so just paste the code inside the curly brackets.
[image]

Comment: Working like charm..

Answer (score 3):

Adding an item called javascript with value javascriptreact in the emmet section in settings worked for me.

[a screen shot of my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aWyD.png)

Comment: Simplest and easiest solution. 

Answer (score 2):

It took me two steps to get auto-closing tags in JSX.

1. Follow Kehkashan Fazal's instructions above about setting `"emmet.includeLanguages"`
2. Download the Auto Close Tag extension from VSCode (`formulahendry.auto-close-tag`)

And now you have nice auto-closing JSX tags!

Answer (score 2):

Follow these two steps only:

1. On bottom of VSCode where detect language click on that

[1st step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlgUF.png)

2. Click on "Configure 'Javascript(Babel)' language based settings..." or what ever

[2st step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2fel.png)

3. paste this code on it separate first by comma ',' and save it.

`"emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact"
 },
 "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true`

[3rd step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2fel.png)

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete for React Babel was working fine until yesterday for me.

None of these answers helped so I just restarted my computer. Worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on various projects and I have a big settings file.

I checked settings and found out that this settings was ruining that all.

```
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly"
```

So I commented it. And everyhting works perfectly in React Apps.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only work in JSX files. Let it not work with JS.

```
"files.associations": {
"*.js": "javascript",
"*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
},
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascriptreact": "javascriptreact"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

just name the file you are working on from `.js` to `.jsx` and you are fine .

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > extensions > emmet > include languages and add javascript as the item and javascriptreact as the value

Answer (score 0):

Go to File--> Preferences-->Settings
In the settings search for "emmet"

Add the settings under Emmet:Include Languages as

Item as javascript and value as html

[Image for the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmfuz.png)

However this works only for html tags.