# Unable to autocomplete tags in reactjs jsx

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, editor, jsx

How can I autocomplete closing tags while coding in react development in Visual Studio Code?

Are there any packages to be installed?

Its time consuming to write HTML elements each time.

Comment: Autocompletion is an editor feature. So we can't answer this question until you tell us which editor you are using.

Comment: in Visual studio Code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSX or HTML autocompletion in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vs code auto closing is available as a plugin, "Auto Close Tag". Simply installing the plugin is enough. See this [gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag/master/images/usage.gif)

Comment: In react application inside { } we have html elements, these html elements cannot be autocompleted

Comment: Auto completion or auto closing? Autoclosing of tags can be done with this plugin. And if its auto completion, its not tags, its react component.

Comment: Please accept it as answer if you find this as a solution for the stack overflow community and upvote if you find it useful

Comment: In case anyone else was confused, this is the plug-in @RohithMurali is refering to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag

Answer (score 0):

To enable autocomplete, you can add this code to your setting config file.

```
     "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    },
```