# React suggestions and autocomplete does not work for files with js extension in VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autosuggest

I need to enable React related suggestions and autocomplete but in files with `.js` extension in Visual Studio Code. The only way to make it working for me is to change extension from `.js` to `.jsx`. I tried everything described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code/) but nothing worked for me.

Here is what I mean by React related suggestions and autocomplete.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

`"*.jsx"` extension assosiacted with **`javascriptreact` language mode**.

Change the file type from `javascript` to `javascriptreact`, you can do it from the bottom panel.

Or run `Change language Mode` from command palette (`ctrl+p`).

Also, you can add `files.associtiations` on your `settings.json`:

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.react.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.jsx": "javascriptreact",
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
  }
```

[image: Language Mode]

Comment: I also have tried this. But it didn't work for me, it only enables Emmet, but not giving React specific suggestions and autocomplete. It is really weird, because the only thing which can trigger enabling suggestions is when I am manually chaining file extension from `.js` to `.jsx`. Even when I am setting language mode to `javascriptreact` does not enabling suggestions.

Comment: This is the official way, there is no enought context to help your issue further

Comment: I have associated javascript file with javascriptreact, but [here](https://imgur.com/a/y4Xj6iz) is what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having same problem but when I keep index.js file open in background everything just works. You can also try

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).