# vscode auto-import suggestions not working inside html tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

Vscode suggest auto-import for component as Parent [image]

but this doesnt work if i try to use auto-import inside html/Component tags

[image]

Are there solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code), what goes inside the return statement in React is JSX, not HTML, and the emmet abbreviation for JSX is disabled by default. To make it work as if you are working with normal HTML, you need to edit the settings. You can follow the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320393/jsx-or-html-autocompletion-in-visual-studio-code)  and it should work fine. Let me know if you still weren't able to configure it.

Comment: this didn't work for me, auto-imports and suggestions still doesn't work, but also vscode doesn't suggest already imported components

Answer (score 0):

As one of the developers on github explained to me, any text inside jsx is just a text, if you wanna have auto import component u need to write inside tag ('<ComponentName.....') or in jsx expression, so auto import will work fine